# Different app.yaml for given subdomain

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, app.yaml

We are developing our app locally on local.website.com, then uploading it to staging.website.com and finally to live environment - website.com. Those are 3 different servers.

We've added following code to app.yaml:

```
- url: /static/img
  static_dir: static/img
  secure: always
  expiration: "21d"
  http_headers:
    Cache-Control: "public, max-age=1814400"
```

But unfortunatelly this Cache-Control interferes with our other scripts, while building locally on local.website.com.

Is there any way to create different app.yaml for each subdomain, or build some logic around app.yaml to disable caching while on local.website.com?

We are using Python 2.7 with Django framework.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks, like Django, Flask, etc., so you can easily add some middleware?

Comment: Yes, we have a little bit of code written in Django.

Comment: Sorry, the app.yaml static handler never gets to the middleware.  Still thinking...